# Fabric Mod Creation error trying to run client through vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, minecraft-fabric

Can someone help find the problem?
`The supplied phased action failed with an exception. A problem occurred configuring root project 'GrassyMod'. Build file 'C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\GrassyMod\build.gradle' line: 2 An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'fabric-loom', version: '0.11-SNAPSHOT'] Failed to apply plugin 'fabric-loom'. You are using an outdated version of Java (11). Java 17 or higher is required. The JAVA_HOME environment variable is currently set to (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2).`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide more information, such as the tool used and the version number, and what you expect. The content given at present is not enough for us to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Java is mentioned at the end of the error report_ The home setting is inconsistent with the Java JDK version number actually used. Please confirm whether your system environment setting and Java setting are correct and use java17 as required.`You are using an outdated version of Java (11). Java 17 or higher is required.`

Comment: Yes, I did find that, and I did somehow fix it, but thnak you for trying to help

Comment: @Chanlanfan That's really good.I hope you can share your solutions so that others can quickly solve the same problems in the future.